# How to give custom password during initialization (first time) of jenkins setup?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, automation

I want to automate Jenkins setup using written inside user data section of my EC2 instance, I don't have SSH access to that instance, but port 80 and 8080 is open, What is the mechanism by which I can automate this stuff?

Comment: You would use Userdata scripting for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to automate the installation of a Jenkins software on a EC2 Instance?

You could have a look at [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/)
They have a Jenkins package, https://chocolatey.org/packages/jenkins

Comment: No, my question is how I can change "initialAdminPassword" as my custom password during installation of Jenkins